# Получить объект с народных карт

Tags: yandex-geocoding-api

Скажите, есть ли какая-то возможность получить объекты с народных карт?
Вот например, [тут](https://n.maps.yandex.ru/#!/objects/3574563605?z=17&ll=30.050162%2C59.354929&l=nk%23sat) есть здание 59.354841, 30.051525.

[image: Желтый квадратик]

Собственно мне надо получить через API информацию объ этом здании (хотябы название и тип объекта, и желательно полигон координат).

Скажите, как это можно сделать, желательно через стандартные API (https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/input_params-docpage), а не через JS Api.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, у НЯК нет публичного api. Можете попробовать подглядеть что браузер запрашивает

Answer (score 0):

[Народная карта](https://n.maps.yandex.ru) Яндекса является основой для публичной [Яндекс.Карты](https://yandex.ru/maps), а через API Яндекс не даёт получать от сервиса границы уровня меньше, чем [регионы](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/regions-docpage/). Поэтому и возможности получить форму геообъектов нет (и этажность, кстати, тоже).

Но узнать адрес дома, если он уже внесён в базу Яндекса (фактически основную характеристику здания), вы всегда можете через [геокодер](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/) или [JavaScript API Яндекс.Карт](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/).